# Question about planetary boundary (multichoice)

Tags: planetary-boundary-layer

[image]

Why am I incorrect? Aerosols absorb energy right? (Click the image)

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is the last option about aerosols such as sulfates altering the albedo.

Regarding your choice, if aerosols absorb energy, what do they do with that energy? Do they internalize the energy or do they radiate the energy out? Either way, what ultimately happens to the energy?

Sulfate aerosols can change the albedo by **reflecting** the energy away from Earth & back into the cosmos.